# For which values of $z$ does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{nz}}{n^2}$ converge?

Tags: complex-analysis

For which values of $z$ does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{nz}}{n^2}$ converge?

My approach:

$$\left |\frac{e^{nz}}{n^2}  \right |=\frac{e^{\Re(nz)}}{n^2}=\frac{{e^{nx}}}{n^2}$$

I want to say that this series converges for all $z$. Can any of you concur?

Comment: or should I use the fact that $\sum e^z=\frac{z^n}{n!}$ and say it's similar to this therefore converges for all $z$?

Comment: Using the series definition does not work. Consider the ratio test.

Comment: Use the Ratio Test, or the Root Test. It definitely does not converge for all $z$.

Comment: I think it would only converge for $z=\beta i$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$ and $u_n(z)=\frac{e^{nz}}{n^2}$ then by the ratio test we have

$$\left|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}e^x<1\iff x<0$$
hence if $\Re(z)<0$ then series is convergent and it's easy to see that if $\Re z=0$ then the series is also convergent, we conclude that
$$\text{the series is convergent}\iff \Re z\le0$$

Answer (score 1):

This does not converge for all $z$. Note that if $z = 1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^n}{n^2}$ diverges. In fact, $e^n$ grows faster than $n^2$.

It converges for $\Re(z) \leq 0$. Use the ratio test, and it leads to $|e^z|< 1$, which is then $\Re(z) < 0$. Then check the boundary $\Re(z) = 0$ and it converges absolutely since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.